# Not able to access Apache welcome page in Azure

Tags: apache-2.4, redhat, httpd, rhel7

I have an RHEL7 on one of the Azure instance and I have installed `httpd` there. Now I am trying to access the url, which is like `myhostname-eastus.cloudapp.azure.com`, but it is timedout. I tried to ping to this address, but it is also timing out. However, I am able to SSH to this doamin. I have the port 80 open, but it is not working again reloading the firewall. Following is the output of `lsof`

```
lsof -i -P |grep http
httpd    28060     root    4u  IPv6 24469984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    28061   apache    4u  IPv6 24469984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    28062   apache    4u  IPv6 24469984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    28063   apache    4u  IPv6 24469984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    28064   apache    4u  IPv6 24469984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd    28065   apache    4u  IPv6 24469984      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

and `netstat` is giving the following info :

```
netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2168/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      28060/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2168/sshd
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the configuration of a Linux VM only enables inbound SSH.  You’ll need to enable inbound port 80 on the NSG associated with the public IP address (NIC/subnet/etc.)

ICMP isn’t supported at all.